# Is this coffee ratio calculation correct?

Tags: coffee

On the Folgers website, it has a calculator.  Place the number of 'cups' of coffee you desire and it tells you how much coffee to use and how much water to use.  I put 8 cups, and it gives the following. 'For 8 servings of coffee use 8 tablespoons of ground coffee and 6 cups of water.'  What?!?!?!  is this 6 eight ounce cups for 8 six ounce cups of coffee?

Comment: Stick to grams and milliliters ;)

Comment: I wish, @Max. You know how hard it is to live a metric life in a non-metric society? Apart from lab equipment, that is.

Comment: But yes. A "cup of coffee" is not 1 cup by volume.

Answer (score 9):

Yes. Strangely, a standard "cup" of coffee (at least in the US) is 6 ounces (177ml). That's especially weird since most of us drink huge mugs. Go figure. So according to Folgers, to make 8 "servings" (48 ounces, 1.4 liters) you should use 8 tablespoons of coffee (42 grams) and 6 cups (48 ounces, 1.4 liters) of water. See also: [Is a "cup" on a coffee maker always 6 oz? Is this a standard in the US?](https://cooking.stackexchange.com/questions/25041/is-a-cup-on-a-coffee-maker-always-6-oz-is-this-a-standard-in-the-us?rq=1)

Comment: yes I already read that... which does not answer the question... 1 tablespoon of coffee for each 'cup' of 'assumed' brewed six oz cup... using eight oz of cold water?  So for the 8 'cup' equation, 8 tablespoons of grounds and 6 cups of eight oz each cold water?

Comment: @Crash Yes, so according to Folgers, to make 8 "servings" (48ounces) you should use 8 tablespoons of coffee and 6 cups (48ounces) of water.

Answer (score 1):

One Tbs of ground coffee brewed in 6 oz of water is a common recipe for a single serving of coffee. The phrase "a cup of coffee" uses the word "cup" in a sense that does not mean "8 ounces" ... understandably confusing. In the end, you should adjust the ratio of coffee to water to suit your tastes and the particular roast.

Answer (score 1):

I prefer to weigh the coffee. Most home coffeemakers are "10-cup". A good starting point is 1.25 to 1.5oz of ground coffee (use more if it's a coarse grind) per 10-cup pot.

For commercial 12-cup brewers, start at 1.5oz and work up... 1.75 or 2oz is generally ideal.

Starbucks uses almost 3oz to brew a pot, but they are doing all of the following:
-Using a gourmet coffee
-Using a very coarse grind
-Brewing it wayyyyyyy too strong

Keep in mind for lower quality coffees (e.g. Folgers) with a lot of Robusta (vs Arabica) coffee in it, you'll need less coffee to get the same strength.

Comment: Hard to go wrong, measuring by mass.